# Flex 4.6 IOS screen doesn't unpan after softkeyboard is dismissed

Tags: ios, apache-flex, flex4, keyboard

I am writing an app for IOS and Android using Flex 4.6.  Everything is working fine on Android, but on IOS after the softkeyboard appears and the screen pans, when the keyboard is dismissed the screen never pans back down.  The bottom half of the screen stays white and the top half remains shifted out of view.  I have been searching online and through my code trying to figure out what could be wrong and I've had no luck.  I have been running the program in debug mode, but no AS3 error messages are shown.  My trace()s are printed, and the app will continue to work but obviously you are unable to interact with the top half of the app.  Everything works fine if I set the softkeyboardBehavior in the XML to none, but then the user can't see where they are typing.

I have only been able to test this on my IPod touch with IOS 5.0.1.  When I try to run my project in Flash Builders simulator neither the Android nor the IOS version will get past the splash screen.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Did you find any solution I m facing exactly the same problem I m developing An App in CS5.5 professional

Answer (score 3):

I have seen that the softKeyboardDeactivate event from TextInput is not fired, as other actions that the unpan should cause are neither fired.

It seems it's a  Flex 4.6 version bug. (http://forums.adobe.com/message/4068144).

I've found a workaround, it's a little tricky but it works.

Put a new TextInput hidden on top of the View, then on focusOut event on the original TextInput, force focus on the hidden TextInput. Softkeyboard event will be activated for that TextInput and the pan will return to the top of the View, then take off the focus from the new TextInput and the softkeyboard will disappear.

The user will not notice about this tricky solution.

```
<s:TextInput id="ghost" x="-100" y="0" width="0" height="0"/>
<!-- ... -->
<s:TextInput id="original" focusOut="textInputFocusOutHandler(event)"/>
```

...

```
public function textInputFocusOutHandler(event:FocusEvent):void
{
    this.ghost.setFocus();
    callLater(this.setFocus);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the "enter" attribute to your TextInput. It worked for me but now I have the issue where it jumps vs. pan when the soft keyboard deactivates.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that my problem was that I was using the StageText skin for my text boxes, which adobe says in the documentation causes panning and any type of scrolling not to work.  Switching to the old TextInput skin seems to fix the problem, but you loose all the native features for the soft keyboard, which pretty much ruins your user experience unfortunatly.